# Tesla Coil Primary Coil Diameter

Tags: tesla-coil

I want to make a tesla coil with about 3 1/2 or 4 inch secondary coils diameter
With height about 1 meter.I am using 2.5 milimeters copper wire for the primary.Is that primary wire is too small??I can't find any bigger wire on my city.I see other people using a bigger wire for their tesla.And can my tesla coil working properly if i just using the 2.5 mm wire??Thank you & sorry for poor english

Comment: The diameter of the wire is dependant upon the current you intend to pass through it  (not given) so we cannot judge one way ot the other.

Comment: @JImDearden At this stage in the design process, it will be very difficult to calculate the amount of current that will flow through the primary because, without knowing the diameter of the primary coil, number of turns, exact height of the secondary, capacitor size, etc (many of which I don't think bleedingcaps knows yet) it is impossible to calculate. For this reason I would recommend a standard 3/8" to 1/2" diameter primary, because in my experience that is plenty to handle the current

Comment: Perhaps using copper tube and not using solid wire at all.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Agreed

Comment: @derstrom8 I merely point that asking a question about suitable wire diameter requires some indication (not necessarily a calculation) of what it has to do current wise. I totally agree with you that bleedingcaps would be best advised to go with copper tube for this application.

Comment: @JImDearden Yes, I realize my post may have come across in a way I did not intend. I was not disagreeing with you, it indeed does have *everything* to do with the current flowing through the wire or tubing. My intended point was that, since it is practically impossible to calculate (or even have a general idea of) the current flowing through the primary at this stage, to simply "go big" just to make sure it can handle the current. You are absolutely right though -- The amount of current determines how thick it needs to be.

Comment: @derstrom8 no problem and a +1 for your answer which gives some excellent practical pointers on building a suitable transformer.

Comment: I don't think this question should have been put on hold. It is very clear what the OP is asking for (albeit the language barrier has made it a bit difficult to understand up front). The question is intact, though, and has been answered in the comments and in the answer section.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have left out a lot of information. What kind of Tesla coil are you building? A spark gap Tesla coil? A solid-state Tesla coil? A dual resonant solid state Tesla coil? An off-line Tesla coil?

Chances are your secondary height ratio is wrong. For a spark gap Tesla coil, your height-to-diameter ratio should be no more than 6:1, meaning the height should not be more than 6 times the diameter (in your case, 4 inches * 6 means don't make a secondary any taller than 24 inches).

As for your primary, yes -- 2.5mm diameter wire is much too thin. It will add excessive resistance, creating extra losses in the form of heat and will have poor high-frequency performance. Try to find some 3/8" or 1/2" diameter copper tubing. Many times it comes from a hardware store already coiled up. Without telling us your location, it's difficult to offer possible sources for the materials.

So, to sum up: Shorten your secondary coil to 24 inches (assuming you're building a SGTC) and definitely find wider primary coil wire or tubing. Otherwise, it's not even worth building a Tesla coil -- It most likely won't work well, if at all.

Comment: Oh, thank you for all of your answer.Any suggestion for the biggest SGTC i can made with only 2.5 mm wire?? (Secondary height, diameters etc?) I live in small city in Indonesia.No anyone sells copper tubing

Comment: If the issue is diameter rather than quantity, then I guess the OP could use multiple strands of 2.5 to get the primary RF resistance down. Multistrand is not usually seen in TC primaries, but needs must when the devil drives. Perhaps you could point him at the one or two most useful TC analysis/design calculators on the interwebs, which will illiustrate to him the Q issue.

Comment: Personally I would not recommend multistrand primaries, as the magnetic fields may get a little funky. Another option, however, is one that I have seen, albeit very rarely, and that is using a long flat strip of aluminum or copper bent in a spiral (as seen in this image: http://www.tb3.com/tesla/hugecoil/primary/P1050055.jpg ). Just make sure the turns have sufficient spacing between them.

Comment: Here is a better image: http://electrotherapymuseum.com/TTRCOM/gpo2/DSC01505a.jpg